# SharePoint custom permission based on specific Organization Unit in the AD

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

Am pretty new to SharePoint, am working on creating a custom permission that I can deploy I sharepoint. I was hoping to create a custom permission that will read Organization Unit inside the active directory and if the user does not belong to a specific organization unit he will be prompted with access denied.

Is there a tutorial to do such a thing? or instructions as of where to start from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the Below URL

[Security Programming in SharePoint 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/magazine/cc163287%28en-us%29.aspx)